# Markdown citations in octopress

Tags: wiki, markdown, jekyll, octopress, redcarpet

I'm using markdown a lot and would like to have a few pages that mimic the behavior of wiki reference.

For example:

```
Blah blah blah <ref>{{Some Reference}}</ref>
```

I'll be adding a lot of references throughout a few pages and am not sure how to accomplish this behavior in markdown. All the resources I've found require a lot of work to keep track of them, you have to order them yourself, both at the bottom and top of the page, as opposed to Wiki markup which can automatically build the list at the bottom of a page with a simple {reflist}. Something similar to the TOC. Is there nothing like this in Markdown?

How could I extend RedCarpet or another processor to manage ref links throughout the page and build a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way out of the box, but you can use a jekyll extensions such as:

https://github.com/archome/jekyll-citation

https://github.com/inukshuk/jekyll-scholar

Looks something like:

```
@book{ruby,
  title     = {The Ruby Programming Language},
  author    = {Flanagan, David and Matsumoto, Yukihiro},
  year      = {2008},
  publisher = {O'Reilly Media}
}
```

Not sure how easy it would be to use for simple web references such as your example, but it would work.